# How do I query for single object using a foreign key?

Tags: java, ormlite

I have these two classes

```
@DatabaseTable
public class User {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int _id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String name;
    @DatabaseField
    private String password;
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, unique = true)
    private Item item;
```

and

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Item {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int _id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String name;
```

I would like to query a single user from the database using a platform since they are unique, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what a "platform" is.  To query for a `User` that matches a particular `Item` you would do something like:

```
List<User> results = userDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("item", item).query();
```

This returns a list of results.  If there will be only one then you could do

```
QueryBuilder<User, Integer> qb = userDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().eq("item", item);
User user = qb.queryForFirst();
```

It is a good pattern to define the column name using a `public final static String`:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class User {
    public final static String ITEM_COLUMN_NAME = "item";
    ...
    @DatabaseField(columnName = ITEM_COLUMN_NAME, canBeNull = false,
         foreign = true, unique = true)
    private Item item;
```

Then your query can do:

```
...eq(User.ITEM_COLUMN_NAME, item)
```

Notice that although the actual field stored is an integer, the `eq(...)` method is smart enough to take an `item` and extract its id field from it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I am still getting an error. It underlines the  "queryForFirst();" saying that "The method queryForFirst() is undefined for the type Where<User,String>".

Comment: Oh, sorry.  `QueryBuilder` has that method not the `Where`.  I've updated my answer @user1735252.